# How Can I Have an Alert Message Sent to Me When a User Downloads a Document?

Tags: html, coldfusion

I would like to have an alert (via ) sent to me (not visible to user) whenever a user downloads a particular document.  Is this possible?  Could I, for example, insert a `<CFINCLUDE>` inside the HTML `<A>` tag? Below are examples of the two pieces of code that I would like to meld.  Thanks for your help!

`<a href="/path/document_filename" 
        title="Click HERE to download document" 
        target="_window">Click here to download</a>`

How to combine with:

```
<cfprocessingdirective suppresswhitespace="no">
   <cfmail type="html" from="emailaddress.com"                      
       to="webmaster@emailaddress.com"
       subject="subject">
       <p>someone has downloaded this document.
   </cfmail>
</cfprocessingdirective>
```

Comment: Did you try that to see if it works?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, however you need to think about the when the code runs, server side vs client side. CF code runs on the server and has no idea when the link gets clicked. You need to add some client side handling with javascript.

On approach would be to add an onclick handler that would do an AJAX call to a page that sends off you message.

Comment: Plus 1 because I almost always upvote answers from people not yet allowed to post comments.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this approach.

```
 <a href="coldfusionPage.cfm?fileToDownload="something"
 target="_window">Click here to download</a>
```

coldfusionPage.cfm would have a cfmail tag, a cfheader tag, and a cfcontent tag.  It would also have whatever conditional logic is required.

Comment: This looks to me like what I am looking for. Unfortunately, I'm a CF novice and have not used cfheader or cfcontent before, so I will need some more details on what the coldfusionPage.cfm would look like. My research to date describes really complex situations -- I think mine is probably pretty basic, but still beyond me at this point.  Will coldfusionPage.cfm be invisible to the user?  Should not be at all visible - the user should be able to download the document as with normal html without knowing the action is sending me an alert in the background.  Thanks for your help -- and patience!

Comment: The ColdFusion reference manual is available online, for most if not all versions.  You can google the tag <cfcontent> x, where x is your version number, to get the documentation you need.  The documentation also has examples.  Here is the documentation for version 9, http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7c82.html.